# Undeclared Variable C++

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
Weapon SpikeClub;
    SpikeClub.name = "SpikeClub";
    SpikeClub.damage = 25;
    SpikeClub.player_has = false;
    SpikeClub.durability = 20;
    cin >> player_input;
    if (player_input == "Spike Club")
    {
        SpikeClub.durability--;
    }
    if (SpikeClub.durability == 0)
    {
        SpikeClub.player_has = false;
    }
    if (oppArmor_Wearing == true)
    {
        SpikeClub.damage = 10;
    }
    if (oppArmor_Wearing == false)
    {
        SpikeClub.damage = 0;
    }
```

This is one weapon in a prehistoric RPG I am making. The stuff on top is the parameters for damage, durability, etc. my question comes at the point where the code reads

```
if (oppArmor_Wearing == true)
        {
            SpikeClub.damage = 10;
        }
 if (oppArmor_Wearing == false)
        {
            SpikeClub.damage = 0;
        }
```

The error returned is that "oppArmor_Wearing was not declared in this scope". 
Other fixes don't seem to involve the same code structure as mine, but can somebody help me? I know it's a basic question, but I don't remember how to declare the variable in a case like this. (It's been about a year since I did C++, and I'm debugging an old project)

Comment: Which part of the compiler error re you having trouble with? It is pretty clear.

Comment: Well, I don't see `oppArmor_Wearing` declared anywhere in the code that you posted, so I'm inclined to side with the compiler.  Where is it declared and where does this example code reside?  Please post a minimum reproducible test case.  As it stands this cannot be answered but for telling you that your variable is not available in the scope of the example code.

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if `oppArmor_Wearing` is `false` right after you check for `true`. Just use `else`.

Comment: And following that, you never need to compare a boolean expression against a boolean literal.

Comment: @ Ed S.- What do you mean by "minimum reproducible test case"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people already mentioned, oppArmor_Wearing isn't defined anywhere. Based on the rest of your code, here's what I think your code should look like to fix the issue

```
Weapon SpikeClub;
SpikeClub.name = "SpikeClub";
SpikeClub.damage = 25;
SpikeClub.player_has = false;
SpikeClub.durability = 20;
cin >> player_input;

// Add these lines in
bool oppArmor_Wearing = false;
// Make sure you define player_input2 as your input like you did for player_input
cin >> player_input2;
if (player_input2 == "Opponent has armor")
{
   oppArmor_Wearing = true;
}


if (player_input == "Spike Club")
{
    SpikeClub.durability--;
}
if (SpikeClub.durability == 0)
{
    SpikeClub.player_has = false;
}

// changed this to if/else instead of 2 ifs
// although I think the blocks should be swapped because
// if the opponent is wearing armor, your spike club should
// probably do less damage
if (oppArmor_Wearing)
{
    SpikeClub.damage = 10;
}
else
{
    SpikeClub.damage = 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Double check whether

```
oppArmor_Wearing
```

is declared in your Weapon structure.